# Gulp: copy files ending with .html or exclude .js?

Tags: gulp

Gulp: see below as an example

1. How to copy files ending with .html in a directory and its subdirectories?
2. How to copy files that not ending with .js in a directory and its subdirectories.

> ```
> --dirA
>   --dirB
>     --b.html
>     --b.js
>   --dirC
>     --c.html
> --index.html
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jacmoe answered, if you need to get specific files in gulp, use that kind of syntax:

```
'/directory/*.fileextension' //Get all files in directory with .extension
'!/directory*.fileextension' //Ignore files with .extension 
'/directory/**/*.fileextension' //Get all files in directory AND all subdirectories with .extension
```

And remember that gulp paths support arrays so you can write something like that:

```
['!/directory/**/*.js', '/directory/**/*'] //Get all files except .js files
```

Or if needed only specific files:

```
['/directory/**/*.html'] //Get all .html files
```

Comment: Thanks. But why do you use `/directory/**/*` instead of `/directory/**`?

Comment: Well I prefer selecting all files from sub-directories with `/directory/**/* ` instead of  `/directory/** `. If I'm not mistaken,  `/directory/** ` will take only sub-directories but not files.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not totally mistaken:

```
gulp.task('copyHTML', function() {
  return gulp.src('directory/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('copied/html'));
});
```

That code will copy any file ending in `.html` in any directory beneath the `directory` directory.